# Hashtable key depends on where function is defined

Tags: powershell, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm encountering the strangest issue with powershell code.

I have 2 files, A.ps1 and B.ps1. B contains very simple code that maps environment to days of the week, and then uses the current environment to get the correct days:

```
$Location\A.ps1 # import Detect-Environment
$currentEnv = Detect-Environment

# 0 as Sunday, 6 as Saturday
$activatedEnvsAndWeekdays = @{
    [CurrentEnv]::LOCAL = @(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    [CurrentEnv]::DEV   = @(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    [CurrentEnv]::UAT   = @()
    [CurrentEnv]::PROD  = @(1)
}

$activatedWeekdayNums = $activatedEnvsAndWeekdays[$currentEnv]
```

A.ps1 contains:

```
enum CurrentEnv {
    LOCAL
    DEV
    UAT
    PROD
}

function Detect-CinchyEnvironment {
    $hostName = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
    switch -Wildcard ($hostName) {
        '*CINCHYPRD*' { [CurrentEnv]::PROD }
        '*CINCHYUAT*' { [CurrentEnv]::UAT }
        '*CINCHYDEV*' { [CurrentEnv]::DEV }
        Default { [CurrentEnv]::LOCAL }
    }
}
```

Since my current env is `[CurrentEnv]::LOCAL`, `$activatedWeekdayNums` should be the list `@(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`. But it's not! It's `$null`. After much digging, I discovered why.

When I define and call `Detect-Environment` from within my file, the code works fine. But when I define `Detect-Environment` in another file called `A.ps1` and then import it with `. $Location\A.ps1`, it doesn't work, **even though `$currentEnv` says it's equal to `[CurrentEnv]::LOCAL`**. Indeed if I compare the variables obtained by equating`$currentEnv1` (local function) to `$currentEnv2` (imported function), `$currentEnv2 -eq $currentEnv` return True. But the result with `$activatedEnvsAndWeekdays` is different. Totally confused.

Any help is appreciated! Happy to provide more context/code.

EDIT:
`$currentEnv1.GetType()` is equal to:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     CurrentEnv                               System.Enum
```

`$currentEnv2.GetType()` is equal to the same thing:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     CurrentEnv                               System.Enum
```

EDIT2:
To add more info, even if I do `$activatedEnvsAndWeekdays[[CurrentCinchyEnv]::LOCAL]` so I'm not using `$currentEnv` at all, it doesn't return anything when `Detect-Environment` and `enum CurrentCinchyEnv` are imported.

Comment: Function is named `Detect-Environment` but called as `Detect-CinchyEnvironment`. Also, what is `[CurrentEnv]`, an enum?

Comment: It sounds to me like something is the wrong type. `$currentEnv2 -eq $currentEnv` would attempt type conversion to make the right side the same type as the left side to complete the comparison. If you do `$currentEnv2.GetType()` is it the same as `$currentEnv.GetType()`?

Comment: @zett42, apologies, they should both be `Detect-Environment ` . `CurrentEnv` is indeed an enum.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, they are the same. Added output.

Comment: added another edit which indicated the problem isn't `$currentEnv` itself.

Comment: I could replicate the issue which is quite interesting (I have no idea why this could happen) but this seems to fix it: `$activatedEnvsAndWeekdays[[CurrentEnv] $currentEnv]`

Comment: The recommendation as easiest workaround would be to not use reference type keys in your hash, simply use strings instead.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please make it clearer, which code is in which file.

Comment: @zett42, edited question to make clearer

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon so don't use enums, only strings? I did notice it working with strings myself.

Comment: @PythonDeveloper my personal advise, to avoid you future issues would be yes, use strings. For reference, you will notice that if you restart your session and try your script it would most likely work as it did for me but then any future manipulation on the `.ps1` file that contains the definition of your `enum` will result in PowerShell emitting a new type with the same name and a different assembly version (clearly this is a bug)... you can test this yourself by doing `[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes() | ? Name -eq 'CurrentEnv'`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, happy to accept your solution as the answer if you post it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer as was requested in comments. For anyone wondering how to reproduce this *bug (?)*, here is a minimal reproducible example.

- **`script1.ps1`**

```
enum TestEnum {
    Test
}

$key = . .\script2.ps1
$map = @{ [TestEnum]::Test = 'hello' }
$map[$key]
```

- **`script2.ps1`**

```
[TestEnum]::Test
```

If we attempt to run **`script1.ps1`** in a *clean PS session* we should get the right value **`hello`**, however, any subsequent update to **`script1.ps1`** (has to be the `.ps1` defining the [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-7.2)) will result in PowerShell emitting a new type with the same name:

```bash
PS /> [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes() |
    Where-Object Name -EQ TestEnum

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     TestEnum                                 System.Enum
True     True     TestEnum                                 System.Enum
```

And a newer assembly version:

```bash
PS /> [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes() |
    Where-Object Name -EQ TestEnum | ForEach-Object AssemblyQualifiedName

TestEnum, PowerShell Class Assembly, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
TestEnum, PowerShell Class Assembly, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

---

It's worth noting that this would only affect us while working on our code but the bug should not be reproducible on a clean session, in other words, if you wish to use reference type keys on your [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0) and can bear with having to restart your PowerShell session on each update of your code then it should be fine during runtime.

**As a personal recommendation, I would use strings as the hashtable keys to avoid this.**

As workaround, casting the type should fix the issue without a need to restart the session:

```
$map[[TestEnum] $keyEnum]
```